# Swift:"Unrecognized selector sent to instance", Xcode 9.4.1

Tags: swift, uitapgesturerecognizer, unrecognized-selector, xcode9.4

Can anyone help me with this?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.delegate=self
    tableView.dataSource=self
    searchBar.autocorrectionType = .yes
    searchBar.delegate=self
    searchBarView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=false

    let tap:UIGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector(("tapCancel:")))

    searchBarView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    tableView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    tableView.isUserInteractionEnabled=true
}
...
func tapCancel(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer){
    hideSearchBarView()
    isSearchon=false
    print("Tap cancel!")
}
```

Every time I tap the View, it crash.
"unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7feb85d109e0"

I will appreciate any help!
Thanks!

Comment: Use `#selector(tapCancel)` instead of creating it from a string

Answer (score 2):

I believe the reason is due to how method names get mapped between Swift and Objective-C, which underlies the Cocoa implementation and the whole target/action mechanism.

In your case, the **Swift method**:

```
@objc func tapCancel(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer)
```

...corresponds to the **Objective-C selector**:

```
-tapCancelWithSender:
```

**Note:** In order to work with the target/action paradigm (i.e., called by means of a selector), the method needs to be declared as `@objc`. The alternative attribute `@IBOutlet` (for use in conjunction with Interface Builder) also supports this. (tip of the hat to @rmaddy)

In order to remove the "withSender" part and get a selector that matches `tapCancel:`, you need to tell Swift to remove the **argument label** `sender`, like this:

```
func tapCancel(_ sender:UITapGestureRecognizer) // Notice the underscore (_)
```

Also, in line with the comment by @dan, perhaps you can use:

```
#selector(self.tapCancel(_:))
```

or more succinctly, as pointed by (thanks again) @rmaddy, just:

```
#selector(tapCancel)
```

*(Xcode will try to autocomplete it to `#selector(tapCancel(_:))`, but the shorter syntax works as well and the method name is highlighted)*

I was not familiar with the `Selector()` syntax you used, so I tried playing a bit with it, and behold:

[image]
(Selector does not match any method the compiler can "see").

[image]
(After adding "withSender", the compiler can match the method, but it suggests using the better `#selector(...` syntax).

As @rmaddy also pointed out in the comments, using the shorter `#selector(doSomething)` syntax (no colons, no underscore, no `self`) also does away with the problem of whether "withSender" is needed or not.

Comment: You just need `#selector(tapCancel)`. You do not need to add the `_` before the `sender` parameter.. And you need to add `@objc` just before `func tapCancel...`

Comment: @rmaddy Thank you, I’ll update the answer as soon as I get to my desk.

Answer (score 0):

use

`let tap:UIGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapCancel))`

instead of

`let tap:UIGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector(("tapCancel:")))`

And add `@objc` before method `tapCancel()`